# Validation using MetaData API

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

How to validate a package xml using Metadata API?
Similar to what we do with changesets. First we validate, then we deploy.
If I need to validate a list of apex classes and vf pages, how can I do so using metadata API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ANT, you need to set `checkOnly=true` in your `build.xml` file.

If you're using the sfdx tool with `mdapi:deploy`, you can pass the `--checkonly` flag:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm

If you're calling the Metadata API yourself, the DeployOptions on your `deploy()` call need to have `checkOnly` set to `true`:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm

Comment: Yes, I was working with metadata APIs and the checkOnly = true works.
Thanks!